# My Wordpress editor deletes all characters after emoji - how can I fix this?

Tags: embed, html-editor

Here's my issue: I have an Instagram post that I want to embed. I go to Instagram, I get the embed code, which includes emoji, I paste it into the WP editor on a new post (note that I am on the "text" tab, since it's code). I click Save. **The editor deletes the emoji characters, and everything after the emoji. Needless to say, this screws up the embed code and everything fails.**

I can work around this by manually deleting the emoji after pasting but before clicking Save. However, is there a way to fix Wordpress to accept the emoji?

I'm on WP 4.5.1.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Make a new post in WP, flip over to "Text" tab.
2. Go to [this example Instagram post](https://www.instagram.com/p/BEw-6J4Fsf1/), get the embed code (under "..."). Note that embed code includes emoji.
3. Paste the embed code into the new WP post. You can see the emoji pasted in correctly.
4. Click Save Draft.
5. Note that emoji and everything after has been deleted.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Why are you pasting the embed code into the editor, instead of using the built-in instagram oEmbed support? PS: Not sure if this is related to the cache issue I had with oEmbeds containing e.g. Emojis on databases that don't support  utf8mb4 - see ticket  [#36456](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36456)

Comment: MySQL  5.5.48-37.8-log. I tried using the built-in Instagram oEmbed support (where I just paste the URL to the Instagram post) and I get the same results: the post is embedded until the emoji and then is truncated, leading to <div>s left open, etc. Not good :-(